# PHP and MySQL in normalized tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-normalization

I have 3 tables.

Table directory:
id | business

Table categories:
id | category

The third table match the business ID with the category ID
table cat2dir:
id | catID | dirID

First page shows a list of categories. When click on one category, it send the ID on the URL to next page. Next page I want to show the business list for that category.

What is the correct way to write the PHP?

```
<?php
include 'config.php'; // mysql connection

function Getdir($dirId){
    $a = $_GET['id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT dirID FROM 'cat2dir' WHERE 'catID'= '$a'");
    return $return;
```

}

```
$sql = "select *" .
        "from directory " .
        "where id = '$Getdir()'";
```

Comment: i think your request is a little too vague, at stackoverflow we expect you to write more of the code yourself and explain which PROBLEMS you hit; the idea is not that we write your code

Comment: @user1914292 I think the question has enough effort and information to compose an answer

Comment: You could use some extra spaces in that $sql string.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can merge this queries.

`SELECT * FROM directory WHERE id IN(SELECT dirID FROM cat2dir WHERE catID = $a`

Some hints for further development:

- Don't use `$_GET`-variables without checking them
- Use `mysqli` or PDO instead of `mysql`, deprecated
- Remember that `mysql_query` is not return a usable value, your should prepare it for further use. The return of your function will not be the `dirID`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  dir.id, dir.business
FROM
  directory AS dir
INNER JOIN
  cat2dir AS cat 
ON 
  cat.dirID = dir.id 
AND 
  cat.catID = <?php echo $_GET['category_id']; ?>
```

Be sure to do the required sanitation on the `$_GET` value to prevent SQL injection